# Prove a certain limit involving integrals and series

Tags: calculus

**Question:**
Let f>0 be an descending function. $f:[0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$. Prove that for all a>0 that:
$$\lim_{a^+\to 0} a\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(na)= \int _0^\infty f(x)dx$$

**What we know**
We figured using the series comparison theorem that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(na)$ converges and also that it's bounded from below by this integral. Maybe we somehow need to prove that the integral is the infimum of the sequence on the LHS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\Delta x$. The your sum becomes $$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0^+} \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n\Delta x)\Delta x$$ 
Isn't this basically the definition of the Riemann integral for infinite domains?